# EA2-3NJ Relay won't switch, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: relay

I purchases a tube of EA2-3NJ relays from Mouser. Reputable company, not counterfeit parts, yada yada. I try using them with 3.3V coming off a Raspberry Pi and they won't switch. I tried several other 3.3V sources, can't get them to switch. I tried 10 different ones from the sleeve, no luck. Contacted Mouser, after a little back and forth, they sent me a replacement set. Same issue.

Here is the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/212/KEM_R7001_EA2_EB2-1103823.pdf). The coil wants to be connected one way (+/-) and I am sure I am connecting it that way. I am not using a pulsed or waveformed voltage. The 3V model that I am using has a Must Operate Voltage of 2.25V. I tried voltages down to 2V and as high as 5V. Never switched. The contacts will handle 1A at 30V, I was using 5V connected to a couple of LEDs to test the circuit. I tried it both with and without a flyback diode.

So, I don't know what else to try. It's a relay, it's not rocket science. The only thing I can find in the datasheet that might suggest a problem is related to storage time -- no more than 3 months at 70% relative humidity or 6 months at 50% relative humidity. So, could I have received two bad batches from Mouser or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can your voltage sources handle the current, about 50 ma at 3 volt?

Comment: Yeah, in line with what @RobertEndl asked, connect the relay coil to your 3.3V source and then while it is connected use your meter to measure that actual voltage across the coil. If your source is weak or current limited in some way the voltage at the coil may read way lower than what you thought. Don't have a multi-meter? If not then now would be a time to get a digital multi-meter. Essential tool for working with this stuff.

Comment: What coil resistance do you measure? What current do you measure flowing through the coil when you power it?

Comment: Thanks for the great questions. Some of this I had already checked but I forgot to include the info in my question.

Comment: The meter is showing the current draw by the coil is only about 30mA. Using a 3.36V supply voltage, the meter reads 3.10V across the coil. The coil resistance measures about 78ohms.

Comment: I did try 2 C batteries (what I had on hand already in a battery holder) Measured at 3.2V. No luck.

Comment: I don't think so, @jsotola. I tried an HK19F-3VDC relay with the coil in the same place and it switched fine with any 3V-ish supply I throw at it.

Comment: i would tap the relay from all sides with a screwdriver handle .... maybe the solenoid is sticking .... maybe you accidentally bought them from mickey mouser

Comment: lol, tapping didn't help  8(:-)

Comment: Did you try to connect the coil in opposite way?

Comment: OMG! I don't know why I never tried that. Apparently the diagrams in the datasheet are of the relay turned upside-down with the pins up, not from the top down like I always assumed. And there are no markings or square solder or anything to suggest which is pin 1.  Thank you @AliChen.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I will give you the credit.

Comment: The data sheet clearly says "Bottom View" on the page showing the pin layout, and another drawing shows a "pins 1 and 10" marking on the top of the relay.

Comment: @PeterBennett you are correct. I just didn't translate that to having everything reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of small relays are frequently have pre-polarized primary coil, to reduce the switch effort. And there could be a flyback diode inside as well. The datasheets show the bottom view of relays. And the application section states,

> If the internal connection diagram of a relay shows + and − symbols on
>   the coil, apply the rated voltage to the relay in the specified
>   direction.

So, if it doesn't work, it is likely a misunderstanding of relay pinout, just try the opposite polarity.